# нет доступа к переменной после сборки

Tags: javascript, webpack

**index.js**

```
  var P = require('Path.vue').default;

  module.exports= P;
```

затем **index.js** вебпаком собирается в  **build.js**

в **index.html**

```
 <script src = "build.js"></script>
  console.log(P)//не определен.
```

Почему не видно переменной? Как исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменной не видно, потому что модули webpack имеют свою область видимости, отдельную от глобальной.
Вы можете положить свою переменную в глобальную область:

```
window.P = require('Paths.vue').default;
```

Либо переписать код так, чтоб доступ к переменной был нужен только внутри модуля.

Либо переписать конфиг вебпака, чтоб он выставил ваш модуль наружу (опция [library](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-library)):

```
module.exports = {
    entry: 'index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'build.js',
        library: 'P' 
    }
};
```